# How to make a Mac OS X .app with a shell script?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, powerpc

I tried following a few tutorials, but I get this: [image: PowerPC Error]

How can I fix this? I added in a info.plist (I just copied and pasted another app's file, and changed around a few things.)

Also, I used `chmod +x myApp` to make the script executable.

P.S. I am using El Capitan

Comment: We can't guess what you did before getting the error message. Which tutorials did you follow, after which step did you get stuck?

Comment: I created a folder called myApp.app, then a sub folder called Contents, then MacOS, then a myApp shell script that contains `#!/bin/bash ; say "Hi" ; exit 0` (With each of the commands on different lines, and w/o the semicolon).

Comment: A bash script that has it execute bit set doesn't necessarily need to be placed in a bundle to be executed, simple double-click it if just in Finder or run it from Terminal.  If you really want an application bundle then create it using AppleScript or Automator, the latter of which is easy.  Add a Run Shell Script action and place your code in it.

Comment: @user3439894 I tried automater in the method you described before posting this, but the app would not run on the target computer.

Comment: @user3439894 Well, for some reason I can't edit my previous comment. The error was something like 'This type of application is not supported on this computer.'

Comment: Is the target computer the one the Automator app was created on and if not why can't you just create it on the target computer?  Why does it need to be an application bundle, why can't the script just be executed as mentioned in the first sentence of my first comment?

Comment: @user3439894 I do not have access to the target computer, since it is my friends. Also, I need it to open at startup.

Comment: What version of OS X is on the target computer?

Comment: @user3439894 Yosemite or El Capitan... not sure which.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34738/discussion-between-flare-cat-and-user3439894).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, it's been years I use this simple trick to have bash scripts in application (and really really don't understand why all people try so complicated solutions as creating "Contents" folders, info.plist or use Automator or Platypus or so... ????).

1. Create a folder named "YourApplication.app". It can be created at any location that is convenient to your usage. Though, the most OS compliant locations may be /Applications or your own ~/Applications folder.
2. Put your script file directly in this folder the way that suites you the best (Finder, terminal etc). The script must be executable of course (use chmod +x if you need). No need for other folders or file (until you need to call other scripts or executable from within your script of course) The trick is to name your script with exactly the same name as the application folder but without extension. In the case described here the script file must be named "YourApplication".

That's all ! It works on Mac os x since Snow Leopard to Mavericks. If anybody can try on newer OS versions and tell me.

**Note:** The *script* must be at least 28 bytes in size, otherwise it will not execute. It may be padded with blank lines to achieve minimum size.
Also, the first line of the script must be a shebang; e.g. `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/perl`.

[UPDATE]

Answering what @DenisHowe's comment is addressing,
when using this trick, if you want to have the path of the current execution, you can add those lines at the beginning of the script :

```
abspath () 
{ 
case "${1}" in 
    [./]*)
    local ABSPATH="$(cd ${1%/*}; pwd)/"
    echo "${ABSPATH/\/\///}"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "${PWD}/"
    ;;
esac
}


CURRENTPATH=`abspath ${0}`
PATH=$PATH:$CURRENTPATH
```

Comment: Try to add some more lines, it gives you the message you had if there is not enough lines in your script.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the critical missing piece of information and up-voted it.

Comment: OK thanks for correction and upvoting... I've been using this since too long time and forgot about the need for 28 bytes... I don't have any script that small of course :D

Comment: I just tested this under macOS Sierra and it works there too.

Comment: Ok cool. Cheers

Comment: Wow! That works! Cannot believe it. Thank you so much.
Edit: Tested on macOS Sierra

Comment: Well, I couldn't believe nobody has tried this so simple solution before... I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: To anyone trying this, make sure the first line is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @FlareCat In fact, I just checked and I guess any shebang with an existing interpreter will do (tried with perl). If you tried other languages, just tell ;).

Comment: Anyone know how to get the script to change the working directory to the .app folder?

Comment: @bugloaf Found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/214070

Comment: To give it a custom icon, do Get Info, select the icon in the upper-left, then paste a 512x512 image.

Comment: @bugloaf : most of the time I use this scripting trick to kind of "encapsulate" other applications in a process (mount disks, manage devices, agents, deamons or make synchs before launching an app for instance) so I simply use the subsituted application icon by dragging the icon from the source application "Get Info" panel bottom big size icon to target application "Get Info" panel up left little size icon (the plus sign should appear when the mouse is over the little icon and so you can paste at this point).

Comment: For anyone using macOS Mojave - you can use the built in Automator program to do this.  Just use the Run Shell Script action then save as an app

Comment: What if `sudo` is required to run the Script? What ca I do so the script will ask the user for the password?

Comment: @Royi Well it depends vastly of the purpose and the command you need to run as root. You can call an application (open -a ...) that manage admin escalation or you can use the /etc/sudoers file and add the required rights for the application/command to caller/user (most of the time your mac os id/user). Beware of security concerns though, breaking sudo rights is not always a good way to do things. Look for "mac os sudoers" via google you'll probably find many samples (there are some in the file too).

Comment: @Steve Vermeulen : this is another solution indeed though it has already been suggested in other answers and is not specific to Mojave. That's an old feature in mac Os Automator. Though this is not as simple and elegant to my sense. It's only required if you need to pass parameters in certain circumstances (I think of Lightroom Export Actions for instance).

Comment: I would specify that the `YourApplication.app` must be cerated in `/Applications`

Comment: @Igor Fobia, I don't know which Os version you're using, but this trick works from any location, not only /Applications, at least on Mac Os High Sierra and previous.

Comment: Works under macOS Catalina too, thanks

Comment: This still does seem to work with Big Sur. Passing arguments (e.g. file to open) doesn't work for me though. This seems to only work with Automator applications

Comment: @basbebe Thanks for your report. I can't have Big Sur for the moment to look for a solution about the arguments (my two Macs are too old). But I will try as soon as I can. I guess a look in the documentation of "open" with --args may give some more clues.

Comment: opening with `--args` does work. but e.g. opening a document with the created application gives an error in the terminal window: `Unknown command: \Xca\Xfe\Xba\Xbe` (I also get this error if I just append the file location to the command)

Comment: @basbebe , indeed, but I'm not sure it is specific to Big Sur, then. To be honest, I don't use that script application trick if I need the "drag and drop document" functionality, I use Automator instead (with a combination sometimes).

Comment: I love how appifying your scripts makes them instantly execute when clicked and gives them a more prominent position in Spotlight.

Comment: When run as an application your script will probably not have the same environment as when run from an interactive shell.  For example, you may need to set the PATH or specify absolute paths of commands.

Comment: @DenisHowe Indeed. Here is an exemple of what I usually add at the beginning of the  scripts :

abspath () 
{ 
case "${1}" in 
 [./]*)
 local ABSPATH="$(cd ${1%/*}; pwd)/"
 echo "${ABSPATH/\/\///}"
 ;;
 *)
 echo "${PWD}/"
 ;;
esac
}


CURRENTPATH=`abspath ${0}`
PATH=$PATH:$CURRENTPATH:

Comment: Is it possible to show the terminal and ask for input using this solution? I have managed to run the script in the *.app folder but want to print some values and take some keyboard inputs.

Comment: @user62013 At that point I use Cocoadialog for that which can be installed with macports (I'm afraid it's not very well documented by now, though, as it is quite a dead project, but it still works). You  can also use applescript for simple dialog boxes and inputs. On the other hand, to my sense, it's not very interesting to use the solution I gave here (I mean the script in simple app) to use terminal in the end. I think you'd better launch directly a script with terminal by double clicking on it and then use it in a standard way.

Comment: Creating an app this way didn't allow me to create a pkg file, is that something that requires a more complicated structure?

Comment: @ngood97 Can you be more specific about what you mean by "create a pkg file" (process, used software, purpose) ?

Comment: @PierreLagarde yeah for sure! The process I was trying to follow is here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-terminal-to-create-packages-for-software-deployment/ -> sudo pkgbuild –install-location /Applications –component /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app ./Desktop/Google\ Chrome.pkg For some reason the pkgbuild tool doesn't like that structure and gives this error: `pkgbuild: error: Path “<path x>/TestApplication.app" is not a valid bundle component (using destination path “<path x>”)` It's not too important, I'd just like a minimal pkg to test stuff with.

Comment: Actually I was able to make a minimal pkg using this guide: https://matthew-brett.github.io/docosx/flat_packages.html if anyone is looking for that

Comment: @ngood97 ok good, and thanks for your feedback. I must say I was only using this trick selfishly on my own macs. Since it's easy to just bring the bash text to any other mac and the app can be easily build in an easy DIY process, I never wonder how to do a package for delivery. That's an interesting addition for sure.

Comment: How to make it show in the Dock ?

Comment: @TSR Drag it to the Dock as any other application.

Comment: In your `YourApplication` bash script you can call `open -a "Terminal" $CURRENTPATH/visible.sh` to open a Terminal window and run `visible.sh` in it. Useful for showing output or any simple interaction. `YourApplication` is run windowless. (Testet on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1)

Answer (score 20):

The currently accepted answer does not quite work for me.  I get the little broken application icon.

> [image]

The following works for me under OSX 10.15.7 (Catalina).  You can feel free to change the `YourApplication` in all of the following instructions to be the name you really want.

1. mkdir a directory with the `.app` extension in the `/Applications` folder with a `Contents` and then `MacOS` subdirectories.

   ```
   mkdir -p /Applications/YourApplication.app/Contents/MacOS
   ```
2. Move your script into this directory and name it the same as the top application folder but without the `.app` extension and without the shell script extension:

   ```
   mv yourscript.sh /Applications/YourApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApplication
   ```
3. Make sure your script is executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /Applications/YourApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApplication
   ```

Here's a sample application to try:

```
#!/bin/sh
result=`osascript -e 'display dialog "Should I beep?" buttons {"Yes", "No"}'`
if [[ "$result" = "button returned:Yes" ]]; then
    osascript -e 'beep'
fi
```

Your application should now be ready and the script should run when you double click on it.  It's important to note that if you rename the application, you will need to rename the underlying script.

---

To have your application seen by LaunchPad was harder to figure out.  The following seemed to work.  You need to add something like the following into the `/Applications/YourApplication.app/Contents/Info.plist` file.  You might also need to move it over to a DMG file and back to Applications for LaunchPad to notice it.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342335/179850

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>My App 1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

To add an icon to your new application, you need to do the following:

1. Find or create a PNG that you want to be your icon.
2. Open the image in the Preview application – other graphics apps may also work.
3. Press command-a to select all and then command-c to copy it to the clipboard.
4. Select your application in the Finder and press command-i to Get Info window.
5. Click on the icon in the upper left corner of the info window to select it:

   [image]
6. Paste the image from the clipboard which should change the icon.

   [image]

You can also open up the Get Info window on other application, select it's icon, and copy it so you can paste it onto your new application.  After you assign any icon, if you look in your `.app` directory, you should see a filename that starts with `Icon`.

Comment: You don't need to have all those folders in the application one. Just put your script directly in the application root folder (i.e. /Applications/YourApplication.app in your case), and make it executable. It just needs to be at least 28 bytes in size and have a shebang, as any script should have.

Comment: This is all very well, and it works as described, but none of it makes it visible to Launcher, which  is the main reason I want to make my script into an "App" in the first place. Anyone can supply that last bit?

Comment: What is launcher @q.undertow?  Do you mean LaunchPad?  Maybe instructions from here about dragging your new application to the LaunchPad icon?  https://appletoolbox.com/mac-apps-not-showing-up-in-launchpad-heres-how-to-get-them-back/

Comment: Yes, Launchpad, sorry. I'll try that link, but I don't want to mess with the system /Applications area - I have my script under ~/Applications. I had some downloaded apps in there and I remember Launchpad had no problem with that.

Comment: I've added some additional instructions @q.undertow.  My application now shows up in Launchpad.  See if it works for you.

Comment: @all Sorry for late answer, but I wasn't notified of your questions as they were on another thread. You can simply add the info.plist file directly in the YourApplication.app folder. No need for subfolders, as already said for the script. That way, it will show in the Launchpad list as any other application. I'm still using this in Monterey. I can help if something is going wrong for you, just note me here :D. The only limitation is passing arguments. You will need to create an Automator application for that instead.

Answer (score 12):

If it is a simple shell script, then you don't need to wrap it in an application bundle; you can double-click the script itself. However, you won't get the ability to have a custom icon or other things like that.

I think there are a few helpers out there that can wrap simple scripts, but the only one that I have experience with is [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) which allows you to make shell/python/perl/ruby/etc scripts run like regular applications with icons, I/O redirections, etc.

Where Platypus differs here is that you CAN get STDIN / STDOUT through a few different mechanisms, as well as menu bar interactivity. So you get a window where you can interact with whatever script is actually running.

Answer (score 4):

Platypus appears not to be useable from the command line (which  is likely where your shell script is).

This script https://github.com/andrewp-as-is/mac-appify which can be installed with pip for python users (`pip install mac-appify`) appears to carry out the steps in [the answer above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407885/237661).

It can be useful like so

```
pip install mac-appify
appify script.sh  /Applications/$NAME.app
```