# Include icon in manually created .app bundle

Tags: finder, applications

From [How to make a Mac OS X .app with a shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script) I recently learned of a *hack* for creating a .app file from a file folder which contains an application with resources.

The top folder is given the same name as a bash script in the top level of the folder system, except the folder name also includes .app.

What I'm wondering, though, is if it possible to set this .app to display an icon that I provide when the file is seen via the Finder? Or can this only be done by making my folder system a Bundle?

Comment: Yes see Apple's Bundle Programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can change the icon by simply dragging and dropping the `icns` file onto the icon displayed in the **upper left corner** of the `Get Info` window. For example, if I right click on the `test.app` shown in the Finder on my Mac and select `Get Info`, I will get the following popup window.

[image]

Below is a folder with some `icns` files.

[image]

Dragging the `os_centos.icns` icon and dropping over the icon shown in the **upper left corner** of the `Get Info` window, will produce the following change.

[image]

You can convert files to `.icns` by visiting the website https://iconverticons.com/online/. Online conversion is free.

Comment: Changing the icon this way will not stick if you move the app to a different computer.