# Problem when trying to make script as an app MacOs

Tags: macos, script

Followed this procedure: [Mac OS X .app with a shell script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script)  and when i double click the "my app"icon from applications folder nothing happens(it doesn't run).When i go deeper: "my app" > Show Package Contents > MacOs > "my app"(executable), "my app" runs properly.

Comment: I think we need to see the script (or at least its first few lines) and also exactly what files are in the bundle. Also do the example scripts in the answers there work for you?

Comment: The easiest way is to use Automator app to create an application; add the Run Shell Script action, and paste in your script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.