# Simple, free GUI application for running shell scripts

Tags: terminal, macos

I need to teach a non-technical person how to configure and run a series of shell scripts. This person has never used the Terminal before.

The shell scripts look something like this:

```
configOption1 = "abcdefg"
configOption2 = "hijklmnop"

# Do not edit below this line

# ----------------------------

[shell stuff here which runs some `curl` commands to change things on a website]
```

I could theoretically try to teach her how to make these changes in TextEdit, run `chmod +x` in the Terminal, and then execute the script, but this would require navigating files and directories in the Terminal, for the `chmod +x` step if nothing else.

I could maybe also create some type of `make-executable.command` script that sets `chmod +x` on the other scripts, but this feels fragile; I want her to be relatively self-sufficient.

Is there an app that would make running the scripts easier for someone without command line experience? The app that most comes to mind is [CodeRunner](https://coderunnerapp.com/), which I use myself, but it's relatively expensive at $20. It would be nice if there was something free.

Comment: How does the script get created in the first place, how does it get onto the Mac of the user?

Comment: I created the script. I can email them, airdrop them, put them on a USB drive, etc—I haven't really thought about it, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It does, as depending on the distribution mechanism, the x bit will already be set. You could even send us a tar.gz for them to double-click

Comment: See also [How to make a Mac OS X .app with a shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394)

Comment: Why don't you use arguments passed to your shell scripts so as to avoid any need to edit them and thus any error?

Comment: @dan I did it this way because I originally made the scripts for myself and I found it easier. I could change it to use arguments—but I think that worsens the problem for someone who hasn't used the Terminal before.

Comment: If you are hung up on `chmod +x`, then you might consider using `source` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Shell Scripts directly from the free version of BBEdit.

https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

## .command

A simple approach would be to distribute the shell script with the file extension `.command`.

When a `.command` file is opened on macOS, Terminal.app will launch and the script will be executed.

The file may need to be marked executable. If so, distribute the file as a zip or within a disk image.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be marked as an executable after each change? I usually have to, anyway. I don't know a GUI way to do that.

Comment: This is a good suggestion - and have the terminal Prompt for the text options, depending on how complex the text options are.

Answer (score 0):

## AppleScript

The shell script can be wrapped up in a [do shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) AppleScript command. The resulting AppleScript can then either be distributed as text only `.applescript` file, or as a complete code signed application.

See **/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app**'s options for saving in different formats.

### User Interface

Instead of, or in addition to shell script variables, an AppleScript can present a basic user interface.

Apple's [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH56-SW1) is the canonical guide for AppleScript, which includes a section on [Interacting with Users](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayDialogsandAlerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH15-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

## Automator

Although I think for you purposes, Applescript is the better option (see above),

Automator also gives easy access to pre-made GUI functions in many apps.  You can insert AppleScripts to run Shell scripts using variables acquired by GUI popups (or file paths to the selected files, for example).

For example:
[image: Screenshot of Automator action using variables]

However it's a bit clunky for using *many* variables, which is why I suggest Applescript for the GUI directly if you don't mind learning a bit more AppleScripting.
But if interacting with apps, such as files in finder, MS or other apps, Automator is pretty fast and straightforward.